# Can a category in category theory contain duplicate objects?

Tags: category-theory

A category is defined as containing a class of objects, arrows between these objects and composition. A class is defined as a collection of sets (or sometimes other math objects).
Can this collection be of non unique objects? if so it would mean arrow only definitions of categories would not be possible. Also I have never seen a category theory diagram that uses duplicate objects.

Comment: Actually, diagrams may contain the same object in multiple places, like in $a\overset{1_a}\to a$.

Answer (score 2):

A class, like a set, is defined solely in terms of a property shared by members of the class. There's no other structure, such as an ordering of the elements. Every object in the universe gets to ask one question and one question only about the class: "am I a member or not?"; there's no other information to be gotten.

In this light, it's impossible for there to be "duplicate objects", because a given object only gets to ask "am I a member or not?". It doesn't make mathematical sense to ask if an object is in a class multiple times (just like for sets), or whether it's in the class before or after some other object.

I think this is another case of hearing a common word ("collection") and thinking of it in intuitive terms, rather than relying on the precise mathematical definition of a class.

Comment: in that case it would be possible to define a category with objects A, A, A, B, B, B as all this objects can be said to be members of a class, and an arrow from A to B would not match to a particular pair of objects. Arrows alone could not define categories like this.

Comment: The "class with objects A, A, A, B, B, B" is exactly the same as the class with objects A, B. (In this case this is exactly the same as how sets work.) I think you have a mistaken notion of the definition of a class (which is therefore causing you to hae a mistaken notion of the definition of a category), and I encourage you to compare my answer with your notion to see where they differ.